# Android - how to prevent UI lag via Handler?

Tags: java, android, performance

I've got a Handler that runs a runnable task every 2 seconds. It runs a fairly intensive task (executes a shell command). Every time the I run `handler.postDelayed(update, 2000);` the user interface lags (for 2 seconds). How do I stop this lag?

I know there's lag because I have a dynamic interface, so I can move around a view and when the handler is run the interface becomes unresponsive for the 2 seconds.

Is there a way to go around this?

Comment: if you are already using a Handler, use a HandlerThread to run your tssk in non ui thread

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this work on the main UI thread, which is not acceptable for your user to have a good experience, as you have already identified.

You can instead create a new background thread for your handler to run any posted runnables on, which will take the least amount of code change:

```
mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("YourHandlerThread");
mHandlerThread.start();
handler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());

// Now post your runnable, as before
handler.postDelayed(update, 2000);
```

Just keep in mind that you cannot touch any UI elements from this thread, as that is not allowed by Android.

Answer (score 0):

> when the handler is run the interface becomes unresponsive for the 2 seconds

That means that you are doing two seconds' worth of work on the main application thread. Doing 2 milliseconds' worth of work is more appropriate.

The `Runnable` that is passed to `postDelayed()` has its `run()` method called on the main application thread. If this work will take more than a millisecond or two, you should be using something other than `Handler` and `postDelayed()` for your every-two-seconds work, such as a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: I have bitmap cropping operation which saves cropped version in a given directory. It requires no update in the UI. What should I use? A new Thread for each image or an ExecutorService -let's say- of 4 threads?

Comment: @Mehmed: Of the two, I would lean towards an `ExecutorService`, just so you do not wind up with an unbounded number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

`Handler` is a way to run code on the `UI Thread` in Android.

If you don't need your code run on the `UI Thread`, you may want to consider just making your own `Thread` or using an `Executor`.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it. Thanks to everyone notifying me that the Handler runs on the UI thread...
I've now run a separate thread to update the variable used in the handler task:

```
double p = 0;
public void z(){
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            p = a.b();
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
Runnable y = new Runnable() { 
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        z();
        c.setText(String.valueOf(p));
        d.setProgress(Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(p / 100)));
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
    }
};`
```